# ASP.Net Core long time between request received and first line of the controller hit

Tags: asp.net-core

My service is extremely slow when is cold, right after deployment, and when it is unused for a longer period of time (like an hour).
Aside from the controller action itself, the app spends a lot of time when matching the route to the controller action.

```
2023-06-12T09:39:13.855690882Z INFO  [.NET ThreadPool Worker] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request starting HTTP/1.0 POST xxxx application/json 103
2023-06-12T09:39:14.782777792Z INFO  [.NET ThreadPool Worker] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with.....
2023-06-12T09:39:16.981415541Z INFO  [.NET ThreadPool Worker] First controller's line
```

The application runs inside of docker container on top of Google's cloud Kubernetes cluster.
I already tried to "heat up" controllers with running this code every 5 minutes:

```
public class HeatUpService: BackgroundService
{
    private readonly JwtConfiguration _jwtConfiguration;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _collectionProvider;
    private readonly IActionInvokerFactory _invokerFactory;
    private readonly PageLoader _pageLoader;
    private readonly ILogger<HeatUpService> _logger;

    public HeatUpService(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider collectionProvider,
        IActionInvokerFactory invokerFactory,
        PageLoader pageLoader,
        ILogger<HeatUpService> logger)
    {
        _jwtConfiguration = jwtConfiguration;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _collectionProvider = collectionProvider;
        _invokerFactory = invokerFactory;
        _pageLoader = pageLoader;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var actions = _collectionProvider.ActionDescriptors;

        var periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        do
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
                {
                    RequestServices = scope.ServiceProvider
                };

                foreach (var descriptor in actions.Items)
                {
                    var route = new RouteData();
                    foreach (var pair in descriptor.RouteValues)
                        route.Values.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

                    var context = new ActionContext(httpContext, route, descriptor);
                    _invokerFactory.CreateInvoker(context);
                }
            }
            
            await periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken);
        } while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);

    }
}
```

With no success

Comment: Some minor remarks, 'heat up' seems weird, i've known this to be called 'warm up' instead. In my experience the first req. is always slow, but especially so in a debug environment. Are you running prod or debug? Also maybe your warmup code could be more safer by just running an actual http req. with a client? maybe some services still are not initialized when running the code like this.

Comment: It is prod. I will double check it but I'm pretty sure I use c=Release in the build script and runtime/non-sdk docker image as a base.

Comment: JIT has first execution delay, even in production.

Comment: Is it running on IIS?

Comment: Nope. Docker container in the k8s in the Google Cloud